# Charging a super cap with a Li-po battery while maintaining charge

Tags: batteries, capacitor, power-electronics, lipo, supercapacitor

I have a 3 V 100 F capacitor and 400 mAh 35 C battery, the battery is to be charging the super capacitor and maintaining charge until a button is pressed to discharge the super cap. I am stuck with figuring out how to produce discharge curves and energy consumption for the battery. There's a bunch of charging circuits online, its the self-leakage property of the capacitor that is making this difficult.

How do I deal with the self-leakage and charging parameters of the cap and the discharging parameters of a super cap to come up with a model to estimate: time to charge, energy left in battery, and how much energy/voltage drop it'd cost to continuously feed current to the super cap to combat leakage and maintain charge?

Comment: _"its the self-leakage property of the capacitor that is making this difficult"_ how so?